# Highlight/bold one char in label

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, esoteric-languages

I'm programming IDE/interpreter/debugger for various esoteric languages. I would like to be able to bold one character at a time, in varying places (depending on code flow), for the debugger. I'm using WinForms for that. So in short, I would need to be able to bold one character of the text and send it to label. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is actually pretty hard to do, you can't get the required accuracy out of TextRenderer.MeasureText if the surrounding text should look smooth without gaps.  It certainly isn't possible with Label, only RichTextBox can do it automatically.  You'll fight this for a while if you override OnPaint().

Answer (score 0):

You should have to paint/draw text using [GDI API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx) - handle paint event or override onPaint().

Comment: Can this handle printing multiple lines simultaneously?

Comment: You can draw a string at given X and Y.